# Modify SonarQube UI Page

Tags: sonarqube

I am getting started with SonarQube and using 6.7.1 version. I need to modify SonarQube page, adding one more column to background task. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Nope it's not possible.
Which column do you need in this page ?

Comment: I need to show submitterLogin. The data is there but sonar does not show it up. I have tried build my own plugin, i made new page to show the value. But i think it is useless to have 2 page with same content.

Comment: I suggest to start a thread on sonarqube@googlegroups.com to ask if this can be added.

Comment: I have created thread google grup and the respon is quite good. They even make jira ticket for that. Link for jira ticker https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-10450. Link for google group https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/A5ia4B-i6wQ/hRmbxmikAgAJ